# XAMPP Services without admin rights

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I've installed XAMPP v2.8.2 on Some system in XP on which students are supposed to run PHP programs. Student login in system with their username/password (Domain Login). Now the problem I'm facing is students don't have admin right and services in XAMPP (apache and mysql) refuse to start because of insufficient privileges.

So is there any solution that I can allow student to run their program without giving them Administrator rights of the system.